# EDI AS2 HTTP trace?

Tags: testing, edi

We're looking into an AS2 implementation and would like to be able to build meaningful test-cases to be used with SoapUI or Postman.
In order to do this we have two ways:

1. just try to tcp-dump/trace calls from an existing client
2. manually build some simple calls starting from the plain EDI documents

or various reasons we've discarded (1) so we must go with (2) and we need some documentation.
This doc from Oracle is a good starting point: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19398-01/820-1228/agfat/index.html

but we cannot really find a step-by-step guide for building the AS2 request starting from the ORDERS edi document (which we already have).

Ideally I'd like a step-by-step guide which says something like:

1. generate a private cert: +commandline
2. encrypt the EDI document: +commandline +sampleoutput
3. create signature: +commandline +sampleoutput
4. build the S/MIME package: +commandline +sampleoutput
5. send over HTTP/S: +commandline +samplehttptrace

Comment: Couldn't you use something like OpenAS2?  Why are you writing your own AS2 solution?  Seems like you're reinventing the wheel, or could get something in place cheaper and quicker than rolling your own.

Comment: We're not willing at all to re-write and AS2 implementation, our goal was to be able to write some test using simple tools like SoapUI or PostMan, without the need of a stand-alone AS2 client. However we've given up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Sending Message

To send a message we need a file with message to send, two pairs of keys for both sides (each partner has one pair of keys for signing and another pair of keys for encrypting, each pair of keys consists of public and private keys). For this tutorial we will use the same pair of keys for signing and encryption per partner.

**Generate Keys**

Using OpenSSL create two pairs of keys:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout P1_private.pem -out P1_public.pem -days 365
```

The same for second pair:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout P2_private.pem -out P2_public.pem -days 365
```

**Extend Private Key Files**

P1_private.pem and P2_private.pem contain only private keys. OpenSSL supports extended PEM format where both, private and public keys, can be in one file. This simplifies some OpenSSL commands (one file can be given instead of two). This tutorial assumes that this has been done:

```
cat P1_public.pem >> P1_private.pem

cat P2_public.pem >> P2_private.pem
```

Otherwise, check OpenSSL commands manual to see how to specify second file where needed.

**Sign File**

Let's assume we want to send GETMSG.edi file via AS2 protocol from P1 partner => to P2, with signing and encryption. First we add appropriate MIME headers to it:

```
Content-Type: application/edi-consent
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="GETMSG.edi"

UNA:+./*'
UIB+UNOA:0++2289+++77777777:C:PASSWORDA+111111:M+19971001:074620'
UIH+SCRIPT:010:006:GETMSG+111'
UIT+111+2'
UIZ++1'
```

Save new file as GETMSG.msg

Then sign the file with private key of sending partner P1:

```
openssl smime -sign -in GETMSG.msg -out GETMSG_SIGNED.msg -signer P1_private.pem
```

Note: OpenSSL puts old MIME types that start with 'x-pkcs7-*', some applications (pyAS2) can handle only new MIME types without eks 'pkcs7-*'. Just remove 'x-' everywhere from resulting file.

**Encrypt**

Now we have multipart attachment with first part being the file content and the second part is the signature. Now we encrypt it with public key of receiving partner P2:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -in GETMSG_SIGNED.msg -out GETMSG_ENC.msg -des3 P2_public.pem
```

Resulting file GETMSG_ENC.msg can be send now to recipient as request with additional AS2 headers.

Note: OpenSSL puts old MIME types that start with 'x-pkcs7-*', some applications (pyAS2) can handle only new MIME types without eks 'pkcs7-*'. Just remove 'x-' everywhere from resulting file.

**Send via cURL**

To send with cURL we have to separate headers and body of POST request. Remove from file GETMSG_ENC.msg all headers (it shoud start with 'MI..').
Use this command to send it from P1 (AS2 ID: p1as2) to P2 (AS2 ID: p2as2), assuming that P2 URL is "http://localhost:8080/pyas2/as2receive":

```
set NOW=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%

curl -i -X POST-H "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"smime.p7m\""-H "Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name=\"smime.p7m\""-H "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"-H "AS2-TO: p1as2"-H "AS2-FROM: p2as2"-H "AS2-VERSION: 1.2"-H "MESSAGE-ID: <openssl%NOW%@LOCALHOST>"-H "Disposition-Notification-To: response@localhost"-H "DISPOSITION-NOTIFICATION-OPTIONS: signed-receipt-protocol=required, pkcs7-signature; signed-receipt-micalg=optional, sha1"--data-binary @GETMSG_ENC.msg http://localhost:8080/pyas2/as2receive
```

Note: this command would also request MDN with signature (because of presence of Disposition-Notification-To and value of DISPOSITION-NOTIFICATION-OPTIONS).

## Receiving Message

The following will already happen on receiving side. That would include decrypting message, verifying signature, extracting payload and preparing acknowledgment or message disposition notification (MDN). It would also require to calculate hash of received message (MIC) to be send in acknowledgment.

**Decrypt Request**

Using OpenSSL command decode request content saved as smime.p7m:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in smime.p7m -recip P2_public.pem -inkey P2_private.pem -out request.txt
```

**Verify Signature**

```
openssl smime -verify -in request.txt -nosigs -noverify -signer P2_public.pem -out original.txt
```

**Calculate Received-content-MIC**

Digest of received content has to be calculated over original file WITH MIME headers, in our case that is content of GETMSG.msg.

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -binary GETMSG.msg | openssl enc -e -base64
```

Note: in real life receiver has to extract that from decrypted content of type multipart/signed. First part is the received content.

**Message Disposition Notification**

Not signed message disposition notification or acknowledgement would look like multipart report:

```
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type="disposition-notification"; boundary="===============1785295974=="

--===============1785295974==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

The AS2 message has been processed. Thank you for exchanging AS2 messages with Pyas2.

--===============1785295974==
Content-Type: message/disposition-notification; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Reporting-UA: Bots Opensource EDI Translator
Original-Recipient: rfc822; p1as2
Final-Recipient: rfc822; p1as2
Original-Message-ID: <openssl20170706165018@LOCALHOST>
Disposition: automatic-action/MDN-sent-automatically; processed
Received-content-MIC: 1GZ1SDk5vvGz5YFGYP6lfhk4MXE=, sha1

--===============1785295974==--
```

**Signed Message Disposition Notification**

If signed MDN is requested (depends on 'Disposition-Notification-Options' HTTP header) then multipart report shown above is wrapped in multipart/signed. And seconds part is signature of the first part shown above. If we assume that mdn.txt contains not signed MDN as shown above, then to sign it:

```
openssl cms -sign -signer P2_private.pem -in mdn.txt -out mdn_signed.txt
```

Now we need only to add some AS2 specific headers to the top of mdn.txt or mdn_signed.txt, depending on what kind of MDN was requested, before transmitting it over HTTP (taken from actual response of pyAS2):

```
ediint-features: CEM
as2-from: p1as2
user-agent: PYAS2, A pythonic AS2 server
AS2-Version: 1.2
as2-to: p2as2
date: Thu, 06 Jul 2017 16:50:18 +0200
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Message-ID: <149935261885.25752.7388914440262498594@HOSTNAME>
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: pyas2-webserver
```

**Based on sources:** pyAS2 documentation, OpenSSL documentation, NCPDP SCRIPT message example.

Comment: Andrew, this is really helpful, thank you - I'm running through this process and I'm encountering a problem - calling `openssl smime sign` returns an error `Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`. When I open the private .pem file it begins `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` - is there something I have to do that's not specified to convert or import this key to make it recognised as a certificate? Thanks.

Comment: Tom W, sorry about that. I forgot to mention that OpenSSL supports extended PEM format which can contain more then one entity in it. I added new chapter in the beginning called "Extend Private Key Files". Basically, my P1_private.pem contains both, ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY and CERTIFICATE. Otherwise, you can specify two files to OpenSSL smime:

openssl smime -sign -in GETMSG.msg -out GETMSG_SIGNED.msg -signer P1_public.pem -inkey P1_privateonly.pem

Comment: Thanks, that makes that part a little clearer. For context, I am trying to reproduce your approach in a container because it's the most convenient available *nix environment with a version of OpenSSL that will work without...quirks. I'm generating and sending a message that looks encrypted, but the receiver is rejecting it and I'm drawing a blank as to why because this particular implementation doesn't surface any information as to why decryption failed. I'll be sure to write up my findings in an answer accompanying yours when I figure out how to do it.

Comment: Follow-up: I suspect the presence of the mail headers in the resulting message is messing up my AS2 receiver, which is expecting this to be S/MIME encrypted but not formatted as an email; you mention removing these headers from the message manually but I was hoping to automate this; are you aware of any clean way to not emit these headers or trim them from the message before sending? Surely it can't be this difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently been attempting to test a new AS2 implementation using the approach described by [Andrew Haritonkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266877/andrew-haritonkin) in his answer to this question.

I found a few quirks that are worth mentioning in their own right.

- `openssl smime -encrypt` by default emits - logically enough - S/MIME formatted content. This is not accepted by my AS2 decoder - for reference, this is the [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-as2-decode) AS2 decode action. I found that the correct format is specified by adding the `-outform DER` option to the encrypt step, which causes openssl to emit the encrypted message in [DER format](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/DER)
- I was starting with a .pfx certificate generated by Azure Key Vault. I couldn't find a way to get openssl to accept this for signing, so I had to convert it to PEM first. The command line `openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out mycert.pem -passin pass: -nodes` seemed to do the trick. `-passin pass:` specifies the private key password for the input certificate as being the empty string, which it is by default when generated by Azure. Not doing this causes openssl to prompt for the password, which failed the whole process in the context I was using it (a Docker container). `-nodes` means "no DES" not "nodes" and indicates that the private key should not be encrypted or protected by a passphrase in the output certificate. Needless to say this sounds like quite a high-risk piece of data to be handing around because it has no protection whatsoever against compromise of the private key.